# GridSearchCV: "TypeError: 'StratifiedKFold' object is not iterable"

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search, sklearn-pandas

I want to perform GridSearchCV in a RandomForestClassifier, but data is not balanced, so I use StratifiedKFold:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

param_grid = {'n_estimators':[10, 30, 100, 300], "max_depth": [3, None],
          "max_features": [1, 5, 10], "min_samples_leaf": [1, 10, 25, 50], "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()

clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold()).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-597-b08e92c33165> in <module>()
     9 rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
     10 
---> 11 clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold()).fit(X_train, y_train)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py in fit(self, X, y)
    811 
    812         """
--> 813         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    559                                     self.fit_params, return_parameters=True,
    560                                     error_score=self.error_score)
--> 561                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
    562                 for train, test in cv)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    601 
    602         with self._lock:
--> 603             tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
    604             if len(tasks) == 0:
    605                 # No more tasks available in the iterator: tell caller to stop.

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __init__(self, iterator_slice)
    125 
    126     def __init__(self, iterator_slice):
--> 127         self.items = list(iterator_slice)
    128         self._size = len(self.items)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    560                                     error_score=self.error_score)
    561                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
--> 562                 for train, test in cv)
    563 
    564         # Out is a list of triplet: score, estimator, n_test_samples

TypeError: 'StratifiedKFold' object is not iterable
```

When I write `cv=StratifiedKFold(y_train)` I have `ValueError: The number of folds must be of Integral type.` But when I write `cv=5, it works.

I don't understand what is wrong with StratifiedKFold

Answer (score 10):

### I had exactly the same problem. The solution that worked for me is to **replace**:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

### **with**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

---

**Then it should work fine.**

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is an API change as mentioned in other answers, however the answers could be more explicit.

The `cv` parameter documentation states:

> cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
>
> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs
>   for cv are:
>
> - None, to use the default 3-fold cross-validation, integer,
>     to specify the number of folds.
> - An object to be used as a
>     cross-validation generator.
> - An iterable yielding train/test splits.
>
> For integer/None inputs, if y is binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold
>   used. If the estimator is a classifier or if y is neither binary nor
>   multiclass, KFold is used.

So, whatever the [cross validation strategy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) used, all that is needed is to provide the generator using the function `split`, as suggested:

```
kfolds = StratifiedKFold(5)
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, parameters, scoring=qwk, cv=kfolds.split(xtrain,ytrain))
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `cv=StratifiedKFold()).fit(X_train, y_train)` should be changed to `cv=StratifiedKFold()).split(X_train, y_train).`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error.  this line: clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold()).fit(X_train, y_train) just defines the object clf and then it calls the fit method to train/fit the clf.

Comment: @rll also mentioned that fit should be replaced with split.

Answer (score 0):

The api changed in the latest version. You used to pass y and now you pass just the number when you create the stratifiedKFold object. You pass the y later.

Comment: I write `cv=StratifiedKFold(10)` and get `TypeError: 'StratifiedKFold' object is not iterable` When should I pass y?

Comment: In the current version you import sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold. And then you can do cv=StratifiedKFold(10) and there should be no error. However maybe you are importing from the previous module which still exists for compatibility purposes until version 20.

Comment: Could I ask one more question? I downloaded from this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn file scikit_learn-0.18-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl, installed it, but now I get `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. `.  What is wrong?

Comment: Probably missing a dependency somewhere. The easy way is to download anaconda. Then it just works.